# python, sort doesn't work (random result)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python code:

```
def calcCompetitionsResults(competitors_in_competitions): #competitors_in_competitions is list of dictionaries

    competitions_champs = []
    competitions = {elem['competition name']: elem['competition type'] for elem in competitors_in_competitions}
    for compitition in competitions:
        list = [elem for elem in competitors_in_competitions if elem['competition name'] == compitition]
        print(list)
        list = sorted(list, key=itemgetter('result'), reverse=True)
        print(list)
```

output: (Before)

> [{'competition name': 'high_jump', 'competitor id': '2', 'competition
>   type': 'untimed', 'result': '101', 'competitor country': 'USA'},
>   {'competition name': 'high_jump', 'competitor id': '1', 'competition
>   type': 'untimed', 'result': '96', 'competitor country': 'Canada'},
>   {'competition name': 'high_jump', 'competitor id': '1', 'competition
>   type': 'untimed', 'result': '100', 'competitor country': 'Canada'},
>   {'competition name': 'high_jump', 'competitor id': '3', 'competition
>   type': 'untimed', 'result': '90', 'competitor country': 'China'}]

(After):

> [{'competition name': 'high_jump', 'competitor id': '1', 'competition
>   type': 'untimed', 'result': '96', 'competitor country': 'Canada'},
>   {'competition name': 'high_jump', 'competitor id': '3', 'competition
>   type': 'untimed', 'result': '90', 'competitor country': 'China'},
>   {'competition name': 'high_jump', 'competitor id': '2', 'competition
>   type': 'untimed', 'result': '101', 'competitor country': 'USA'},
>   {'competition name': 'high_jump', 'competitor id': '1', 'competition
>   type': 'untimed', 'result': '100', 'competitor country': 'Canada'}]

as you can see it wasn't sorted at all according to result field...

Comment: Please **DONOT** use `list` as a variable name. Python uses `list` for `list()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `result` are string so you should convert it to `int` first, also please don't use `list` as variable name as python already used it, here I replaced `list` with `l`:

```
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x['result']), reverse=True)
```

Comment: how to convert that to int, could you edit my solution?

Comment: why not just use my solution?

Comment: anyway you can convert it to `int` in a seperate line before calling `sort`

Comment: what is your solution? I dont see it

Comment: well change your `list = sorted(list, key=itemgetter('result'), reverse=True)` line to mine `l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x['result']), reverse=True)` (do remember to change the variable name)